# Getting an Error in Trailhead Analyze Your Code and Deploy It to Your Org in MyFirstWebComponent -

Tags: lightning-web-components, vs-code, trailhead

Getting an Error in Trailhead Analyze Your Code and Deploy It to Your Org in MyFirstWebComponent
While I'm able to create all the components in Visual Code and push them to the Salesforce Trailhead playground org, when I try to add it to the Page in the last step - I get this error -
Error during LWC component connect phase: [contact is not defined]

[image: Error message in salesforce]

Answer (score 0):

AFter resaving, and pushing again, then re-opening org, I then deleted a component on the page that had a permission error showing (it showed last time too), but after that I was able to drag the LWC component onto the page successfully.